# Internal Server Errors are mapped to 302 Found with a redirect to "/offline_pages/" on Swisscom CloudFoundry

Tags: cloud-foundry, http-status-codes, http-status-code-500, swisscomdev

We are using the Swisscom CloudFoundry solution with a Java and a Node.JS application. Since very recently, every HTTP status code starting with 5xx (tested with `500` and `503`) is automatically mapped to the status code `302 Found` with a redirect header to `/offline_pages/` (tested with `DELETE`, `POST` and `GET`). This is done in-between our application and the front-end, requesting a resource with a status code `5xx`.

We are actively using the `5xx` status codes to report a server error to the front-end over our REST API (including maintenance down-time etc.). This does not work anymore, because of the automatic mapping. For instance, there is no automatic redirect to a maintenance page anymore, because the front-end does not see `3xx` status as an error.

This issue occurs in both our applications (Java and Node.JS). The logs, however, display the correct `503` respectively `500` error. Furthermore, in our application's code base the redirect URL string `/offline_pages/` is not even present; which leads to the conclusion, that this must be done outside of our application.

If a visible browser page returns a `500` the user is actually redirected to the page `/offline_pages` which displays a Swisscom error page. This error page (to which it redirected), then returns a `200` status code on its part, making it impossible to automatically detect the error in a Kiosk browser.

**Is there any possibility to configure the Swisscom CloudFoundry to deactivate this behavior, which is suddenly occurring?**

---

This is the request made by the front-end:

```
GET /api/account HTTP/1.1
Host: <HOST>
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
User-Agent: <USER-AGENT>
Referer: <REFERER>
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: <LANGUAGES>
```

And this is the response:

```
HTTP/1.0 302 Found
Location: /offline_pages/
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Length: 0
```

Excpected is the same as in the server logs, in this case a `503`. Here are the logs for this request:

```
2017-11-14 13:54:07 [RTR/1] OUT <HOST> - [2017-11-14T12:54:07.455+0000] "GET /api/account HTTP/1.1" 503 [...]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There has been a reconfiguration of Swisscoms load balancer that caused this weird behavior. It should be fixed now.